# no content to map due to end of input - In Camel

Tags: apache-camel, unmarshalling

I am new to using Camel. I am getting expected response from the url i hit - which i have logged. But after receiving the message I get the error following error while unmarshalling it:

On delivery attempt: 0 caught: com.fasterxml.json.databind.JsonMappingException: no content to map due to end-of-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I solved this issue:

I autowired the `DefaultCamelContext` bean in my `routeBuilder` class and set the stream caching to true. This will set stream caching to true globally.

```
@Autowired
DefaultCamelContext camelContext;
```

Then set stream caching to true:

```
 camelContext.setStreamCaching(true);
```

Alternatively you can also set stream caching true for a single router as follows:

```
from("jbi:service:http://myService.org")
    .streamCaching(true)
    .to("jbi:service:http://myOtherService.org");
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe its due to streaming - can only read once problem, and since you logged it, its empty. See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

Comment: I got the camelContext in my routeBuilder class and set the stream caching to true: ---   camelContext.setStreamCaching(true);

Comment: Only interesting thing was, i was able to run the same code in my local windows machine with no problems, however when deployed in linux environment, i was getting same exception and streamCaching saved the day.